# PHP page not receiving POST data

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, post

I've made a little function that sends data from two forms to a PHP page, and I read it was possible to serialize two forms and send those in one POST request, but for some reason it's just not working: the PHP page is not receiving the POST data...

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code for the serialization of the two forms:

```
$.post("orderform.php", $("[name=setupform], [name=passengersform]").serialize(), function(data) { 
    /*-here is a function to change the layout-*/ } );
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Is the form submitting at all? Is the data wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to repeat the title: the PHP page is not recieving the data.

Comment: Are you using firefox/firebug? Have you checked what is your page sending out inside the HTTP request?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's error console for JavaScript errors? For one, you're not closing your `$.post()` (needs `);` at the end).

Comment: @GEMI: Firefox, yes, Firebug, no. How could I check that?

Comment: @JamWaffles: Yes, totally clean, no errors. I did close my post() function, just forgot to type it in the startpost. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Jasper: I actually read that one, and that is where I got my code, as they used: `$('#form1, #form2').serialize();` Unfortunatly, as I pointed out, that code didnt work for me.

Comment: `<input name="a" value="b"><input name="a" value="c">` serialize this would give `a=b&a=c` (jQuery won't kick one value out) php can't handle two same names. Make sure that this is not your problem.

Comment: @micha: Yep, I've covered that, All input names are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.post("orderform.php", 
        $('form[name="setupform"], form[name="passengersform]"').serialize(), 
        function(data) { 
} );
```

Comment: Wow, that works :D can you perhaps explain why?
also, you added quotes around setupform, I removed those.

Comment: simple, just added the name of the node where the name will be compared

Comment: So now it only looks for forms with these names?
And btw, you totally messed up your quotes in the code now, haha ;)

Comment: Exactly, they are small things, but that make all the difference!, Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple, serialize does not work that way, he builds a query string, and you are expecting to receive a POST on the server, which in the case is going blank

http://jqapi.com/#p=serialize

> Encode a set of form elements as a **string** for submission

Maybe that is one of the possible problems, since the debug request?

Comment: Then why does serialize work with just one form?

Comment: Yep, [name=setupform] works just fine with one form...